# Caption does not appear on Instagram photo after setting UIDocumentInteractionController's annotation property

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, uidocumentinteraction

My app can successfully upload photos to Instagram using `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but I am unable to successfully upload the photo with a caption.

The Instagram docs tell you to do this:

> To include a pre-filled caption with your photo, you can set the
>   annotation property on the document interaction request to an
>   NSDictionary containing an NSString under the key "InstagramCaption".
>   Note: this feature will be available on Instagram 2.1 and later.

I have tried this five times now. I have tried creating an `NSDictionary` several different ways including using literal syntax but I still cannot get it to work so it has to be something wrong with Instagram.

Here is a sample of my code that sets up the document and opens the photo in the Instagram iOS app:

```
UIImage *screenShot = finalImage;
NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.igo"];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.igo"];
NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];

self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
self.dic.annotation = @{@"InstagramCaption" : @"Here's my caption!"};

self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
[self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {

    [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];

} else {

    NSLog(@"No Instagram Found");
}
}
```

Notice how I am setting `self.dic.annotation` properly and follow Instagram's guidelines.

The photo opens up fine in the Instagram iOS app and will successfully upload to the user's profile, but the caption is never included.

It looks like people were having this same problem back in 2013, but then the issue was fixed.

Comment: Instagram does not support  InstagramCaption


http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out.

All I did was move my statement where I define `self.dic.annotation` underneath the following statement:

```
self.dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
```

The above statement is returning a new instance of `UIDocumentInteractionController` and obviously none of it's properties are set.

EDIT: I would advise not to use the original code I posted unless you are willing to make changes. I just noticed that there are two statements returning a `UIDocumentInteractionController` instance and they are both right next to each other:

```
self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
self.dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
```

This code came from a tutorial so I cannot vouch for it's quality. If you want to use it, make sure to analyze it line for line so you don't run into any of the confusion that I did.

EDIT 2:

Here is the final code sample that works perfectly. You should be able to use this with no errors:

```
UIImage *screenShot = finalImage;

NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.igo"];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.igo"];
NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];

self.dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.photo";
self.dic.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Enter your caption here" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];

[self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];

 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {

        [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect    inView: self.view animated: YES ];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"No Instagram Found");
    }
```

Comment: As of August 2015, Instagram is ignoring the InstagramCaption annotation. See: http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing